# How can I create a validation rule based on three picklist values and other values?

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I currently have a validation rule that reads:

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.Name == 'Proposal',
        RecordType.Name == 'Landscape',
        RecordType.Name == 'Forecast'
    ),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Won'),
    Number_of_Opp_Notes__c < 1
)
```

Now, I have the following requirements and I am messing it up:

- When status is won

  - Record will not close without submitted budget information, awarded budget information, notes and country
- When status is lost

  - Record will not close without submitted budget information, notes and country
- When status is no-go, withdrawn or canceled

  - Record will not close without notes

I'm not great with formulas and this is throwing me for a loop. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wouldn't I just need to add the pickvals for stage(status)? The other pieces don't impact because in each requirement if there is no note, it fires. Is that correct?

SECOND EDIT:  Would this work and fill the above requirement?

```
AND(
OR(
RecordType.Name == 'Proposal',
RecordType.Name == 'Landscape',
RecordType.Name == 'Forecast'
),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Won'),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Lost'),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'No-Go'),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Withdrawn'),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Canceled'),

Number_of_Opp_Notes__c < 1
)
```

Comment: I would break this apart into three separate validation rules. No sense in making one complicated one when it seems like the conditions are all a little bit different even if they hinge around `StageName`. Additionally, I would use `RecordType.DeveloperName` rather than `Name`. That way if the record type name changes or you provide translations for the name (in a multilingual org) your formula still works.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: you can also exploit `Opportunity.IsWon` and `Opportunity.IsClosed`